# Embedded Solr- UnsatisfiedDependencyException (Solr Server seems fine)

Tags: solr, lucene, spring-data, spring-data-solr

Getting an Exception with the latest version of Solr 5.0. Goes away with a downgrade to an earlier release(4.10.4) but the version has its own problems (see Exception No.2).

SolrConfig Class

```
public class SolrEmbeddedConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

     @Bean
        public EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean solrServerFactoryBean() {

            EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean();
            factory.setSolrHome(environment.getRequiredProperty("embeded.solr.home"));

            return factory;
        }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactoryBean().getObject());
    }

}
```

Exception No.1: throws with latest version of Solr 5.0

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountTemplate' defined in file [/Users/foo/workspace/ProjectX/build/tmp/tomcatRunWar/work/Tomcat/localhost/com.projecta/WEB-INF/classes/com/projecta/core/api/impl/AccountTemplate.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [com.projecta.core.search.service.AutocompleteDocumentService]: : Error creating bean with name 'autocompleteDocumentService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate com.projecta.core.search.service.impl.AutocompleteDocumentServiceImpl.solrTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/projecta/core/config/SolrEmbeddedConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate]: Factory method 'solrTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrServerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/projecta/core/config/SolrEmbeddedConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'solrServerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.getSolrServer(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer; @4: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab6 0032 b0
; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autocompleteDocumentService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate com.projecta.core.search.service.impl.AutocompleteDocumentServiceImpl.solrTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/projecta/core/config/SolrEmbeddedConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate]: Factory method 'solrTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrServerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/projecta/core/config/SolrEmbeddedConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'solrServerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.getSolrServer(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer; @4: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab6 0032 b0

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar:7.0.42]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autocompleteDocumentService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate com.projecta.core.search.service.impl.AutocompleteDocumentServiceImpl.solrTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/projecta/core/config/SolrEmbeddedConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate]: Factory method 'solrTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrServerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [com/projecta/core/config/SolrEmbeddedConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.solr.server.support.EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'solrServerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.getSolrServer(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer; @4: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory', 'java/lang/String' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab6 0032 b0

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Exception 2: thrown with Solr Version 4 downgrade.

```
21:03:12.818 [coreLoadExecutor-13-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer - Error creating core [collection1]: Error opening new searcher
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:881) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:654) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:491) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:255) [solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249) [solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.8.0]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1574) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1686) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:853) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/Users/foo/workspace/ProjectX/solr_sandbox/collection1/data/index/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:89) ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:755) ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:77) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:64) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:284) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:116) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1537) ~[solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
21:03:14.655 [Finalizer] ERROR o.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter - SolrIndexWriter was not closed prior to finalize(), indicates a bug -- POSSIBLE RESOURCE LEAK!!!
21:03:14.656 [Finalizer] ERROR o.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter - Error closing IndexWriter
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3271) ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3240) ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.shutdown(IndexWriter.java:910) ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:987) ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:957) ~[lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:38:43]
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:129) [solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.finalize(SolrIndexWriter.java:182) [solr-core-4.10.4.jar:4.10.4 1662817 - mike - 2015-02-27 16:43:07]
    at java.lang.System$2.invokeFinalize(System.java:1267) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:98) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:34) [na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:210) [na:1.8.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solr/SolrJ 5 release changed more that the simple introduction of `SolrClient`. Therefore Spring-Data-Solr is at this time not yet compatible with the newer client library. However there's already an issue branch for [DATASOLR-232](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/tree/issue/DATASOLR-232) available on github.

For some reason the 4.10.x version of `EmbeddedSolrServer` sometimes leaves the write lock in place when shutting down. That causes the issue with non starting server. Maybe `<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>` helps.

Comment: the option that worked for the integration tests was setting `<lockType>${solr.lock.type:none}</lockType>` though I would not recommend this for production

Comment: @ChristophStrobl hi Christoph; is there any roadmap for the Spring-data-solr support for Solr 5? I'm using Solr5 as server and spring-data-solr with solrj4 for querying it; for now I have no problem (i'm only querying documents indixed by liferay) but if I need to index some documents I may have some issue

Comment: The Solr5 upgrade (-> SD Solr 2.0) will be part of the Hopper release train since it requires some breaking API changes.

Answer (score 0):

Apart solrClient changes in solrj 5.x they also changed class inheritancy hierarchy which makes spring-data-solr current version 1.4.1 incompatible with solrj 5.x

> HttpSolrServerFactory (spring-data-solr) expects SolrServer (solrj) implementation class (HttpSolrServer) available in 4.10.x version but from 5.x version of solrj HttpSolrServer doesn't extend SolrServer but falls in different inheritance hierarchy of HttpSolrClient which causes the issue.

Need to wait for recent development in process for spring-data-solr which supports 5.x version of solrj. Check [spring-data-solr](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/tree/issue/DATASOLR-232) github